# Why Firebase database (Firestore) does not add documents

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, async-await, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add  usersData with this:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class DatabaseService {

    final String uid;
    DatabaseService({this.uid});

    // collection reference
    final CollectionReference nextCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('usersData');

    Future updateUserData(String firstName, String lastName, String country) async{

        return await nextCollection.document(uid).setData({
          'firstName':firstName,
          'lastName':lastName,
          'country':country,
        });
    }
}
```

calling it when a user registers:

```
Future register(String email, String pwd) async {

    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pwd);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      //Create new document for the user 
      await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid)
      .updateUserData('Saad','AMRANI','laayoune');

      return _userFromFireBaseUser(user);
    } 
    catch (e) 
    {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
}
```

the user registers successfully , but the initial data  with the uid as document uniq key on the usersData collection does not work!

logs screenshot

[image]

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
   firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5 
   cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
```

App build.gradle

```
 defaultConfig {
    // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
    applicationId "com.nextconcept.nextMain"
    minSdkVersion 16 //21
    multiDexEnabled true //added
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}
```

root build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: When posting to Stack Overflow, please don't use screenshots of text.  Instead, copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read and search. We should be able to see all related information without clicking away to some other page.

Comment: thanks for the info  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have the write permissions on this collection.

See [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to manage Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

To allow any logged in user to read and write :

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it Worked .